# Add Language to BlackBerry 9800 simulator

Tags: blackberry

How to add new language?  I cannot find 9800.xml

Answer (score 1):

see blog post [Add Language to BlackBerry Simulator](http://www.gani.com.au/blog/2011/01/add-language-to-blackberry-simulator/) and support forum page [Add language support to the BlackBerry Simulator](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Testing-and-Deployment/Add-language-support-to-the-BlackBerry-Simulator/ta-p/445954)